# Difference between flipping a view using rotation and scale transforms

Tags: objective-c, performance, transform

Is there any *(performance)* difference between flipping / rotating a symmetric image using rotation and scale transform like in the examples below?

```
view.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1, -1);
view.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(180 / 180.0 * M_PI);
```

Comment: I would say, yes there is. Fipping over the x axis makes bottom to top but let left be left and right be right. Rotating make left to right and bottom to top.

Comment: @PeterPaulKiefer, I know this, that's why I stated in the question that it is about a __symmetric__ image, for which the visual transformation is the same.

Comment: A symetric image could be left half black and right half red. Then it is not the same. Ok, I give up. But if you take a all blue quadratic image for example then the effect would result in the same images. However the performance would not be the same. In first row you use constants in the second row you use division and multiplication. And even if you simplify the second row to ...`CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI);` the Matrix must be filled with sinus and cosins values. If this values are computed it costs much if they are taken from a lookup table it's cheap.

Comment: @PeterPaulKiefer, I understand now, you were right. I should have said __horizontally symmetric__ image, right?

Comment: That's what mathematicians love. ;-) But honestly: I think there is no practical difference. I would expect that objective-c computes cos and sin by taking the values from lookup tables otherwise they would have to compute huge recursive sums. But even that does not matter if you  run one time through the code  above. If it is executed e.g. in a loop and a hundred time a second then I would use the first row.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, the two examples you provide are not the same transformations at all. (as you pointed out in the comments; but because of the symmetry it will not matter to you.)
But there is no difference between

```
CGAffineTransformMakeScale(-1, -1);
```

and

```
CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI);
```

`CGAffineTransform` is just a 3x3 matrix with a special purpose. You can find some examples in the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGAffineTransform/#//apple_ref/c/func/CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation). It doesn't matter with which function the matrix is created.

You might be able to check this with [`CGAffineTransformEqualToTransform`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGAffineTransform/#//apple_ref/c/func/CGAffineTransformEqualToTransform), though floating point comparisons could mess up things.

Comment: I forgot that it all boils down to a transformation matrix, but I don't think the matrices will be exactly the same, because if the image is not symmetric, the visual transformation would be different. (Never seen so many edits in a such short time :laughing:)

Comment: The contents of the image are irrelevant. Mathematically, a scale by (-1, -1) is identical to a rotation by π radians. However, `CGAffineTransformMakeScale(-1, -1)` is not equal to `CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI)` because of rounding errors. The rotation matrix contains ±1.224646799147353e-16 in the `b` and `c` fields because `sin(M_PI)` is not exact.